# Cauchy- Riemann Proof

Tags: calculus, analysis

If ${f= u+iv}$ is defined around a given point ${z_0=x_0+iy_0}$, and ${ \lim_{h\to0} Re (\frac{f( z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}) }$ exists, prove that ${u_x}$ and ${v_y}$ exist and that ${u_x=v_y}$.

From the limit we can understand that ${u}$ is differentiable around ${z_0}$ and therefore ${u_x}$ exists, but it is not given that ${f= u+iv}$ is continuous nor  differentiable so we cannot use Cauchy-Riemann to prove that ${u_x=v_y}$! I don't know what am I missing but this is supposed to be the full question and I have to prove it, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the limit as $h \to 0$ through real values must be equal to the limit as $h \to 0$ through purely imaginary values. This immediately gives you $u_x=v_y$.

Comment: Sorry Sir but may I ask, is this a part of the definition?

Comment: When you say limit of $g(h)$ as $h \to 0$  exists you are saying that the limit has the same value in whatever way $h \to 0$.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks a lot! (I'm discovering the subject newly)